# MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration unresolved reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, google-mobile-ads

I need to change MobileAds request configuration but am getting `Unresolved reference: getRequestConfiguration` error.

```
var requestConfiguration = MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration().toBuilder()
    .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE)
    .setMaxAdContentRating(MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_G)
    .build()
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration)
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
```

If I remove the configuration code the ads work without any issues.

How to resolve the reference error?

Comment: Did you try invalidating resources and restarting.

Comment: Yes, I did try that.

Comment: Is your application running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found out myself that the issue was cause by `play-services-ads` dependency version. I had 17.2.0 installed and update to 18.2.0 resolved the issue. I noticed that when reviewing dependences in `File->Project Structure->Dependences` dialog.